# How to properly start a SessionFactory?

Tags: java, hibernate

I will need to be connected to my database in almost every page of my website.

My first page is a Login so I intent to start the `SessionFactory` and keep it open for later use in other pages.

**My question is:** How can I declare the variable global so I can use it everywhere in my other classes?

```
 public SessionFactory StartDatabaseConnection() {
    SessionFactory factory;

    try {
         factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    return factory;
}
```

How do I use it here now?? `factory doesn't exist in context`

```
 private Integer addGeneralSetup(GeneralSetup generalSetup) {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Integer generalSetupID = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        generalSetupID = (Integer) session.save(generalSetup);
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return generalSetupID;
}
```

Comment: where is your `context` ?

Comment: @Ravi what is that?

Comment: your question is not clear. What do you mean by context ?

Comment: I mean, SessionFactory is supposed to be started only once right? I did it on my Login page. But in other page I dont have the SessionFactory object. I need to pass it everywhere? Can't I make something like a GLOBAL variable with the object and just use it everywhere I want?

Comment: Is it a web application ?

Comment: SessionFactory should be started as soon as you application starts up. Assuming, the backend is same throughout.And does not matter with logins

Comment: Yes it's a web application. But look on `addGeneralSetup` method. I use factory object but it doesnt exist there. I need to pass it everytime as a parameter?

Comment: Study about `singleton design pattern`, that is what you need here.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj lol stfu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice in my opinion is to use singleton spring bean and inject the dependency whenever required.

Spring provides 2 ways to achieve this: 
 1. Spring has inbuilt templates ready to be used
    For example:

```html
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

2. You can declare your own bean with default scope and auto-wire it. 
   Example:

```html
<bean id="customBean" class="com.learn.custom.CustomBean" />
```